# Grapher Having Problems After High Sierra Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, macos, grapher

My wife just upgraded to OS 10.12.6.  She uses Grapher to make pictures for work.  Now Grapher can no longer read her old .gcx files.  She had a template she was using a lot.  So, she had to remake the template in the new Grapher.  It worked at first, but now Grapher won't even open that file.  Has anyone had this happen?  Is there a potential fix?  I tried to Google, but no one seems to care about Grapher.

Comment: I am looking for a possible fix as well. I have some Grapher files from a few years ago that didn't open -- I thought perhaps they were corrupt. I tried another that was created in 2014, but I last opened it in July 2017. Now suddenly I am getting this error.